# AND search with reverse relations

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working on a django project with the following models.

```
class User(models.Model):
    pass

class Item(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    item_id = models.IntegerField()
```

There are about 10 million items and 100 thousand users.

My goal is to override the default admin search that takes forever and 
return all the matching users that own "all" of the specified item ids within a reasonable timeframe.

These are a couple of the tests I use to better illustrate my criteria.

```
class TestSearch(TestCase):
    def search(self, searchterm):
        """A tuple is returned with the first element as the queryset"""
        return do_admin_search(User.objects.all())

    def test_return_matching_users(self):
        user = User.objects.create()
        Item.objects.create(item_id=12345, user=user)
        Item.objects.create(item_id=67890, user=user)

        result = self.search('12345 67890')
        assert_equal(1, result[0].count())
        assert_equal(user, result[0][0])

    def test_exclude_users_that_do_not_match_1(self):
        user = User.objects.create()
        Item.objects.create(item_id=12345, user=user)

        result = self.search('12345 67890')
        assert_false(result[0].exists())

    def test_exclude_users_that_do_not_match_2(self):
        user = User.objects.create()

        result = self.search('12345 67890')
        assert_false(result[0].exists())
```

The following snippet is my best attempt using `annotate` that takes over 50 seconds.

```
def search_by_item_ids(queryset, item_ids):
    params = {}
    for i in item_ids:
        cond = Case(When(item__item_id=i, then=True), output_field=BooleanField())
        params['has_' + str(i)] = cond

    queryset = queryset.annotate(**params)

    params = {}
    for i in item_ids:
        params['has_' + str(i)] = True
    queryset = queryset.filter(**params)
    return queryset
```

Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some quick suggestions that should improve performance drastically.

**Use prefetch_related` on the initial queryset to get related items**

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related('user_set')
```

**Filter with the `__in` operator instead of looping through a list of IDs**

```
def search_by_item_ids(queryset, item_ids):
    return queryset.filter(item__item_id__in=item_ids)
```

**Don't annotate if it's already a condition of the query**

Since you know that this queryset only consists of records with ids in the item_ids list, no need to write that per object.

**Putting it all together**

You can speed up what you are doing drastically just by calling -

```
queryset = User.objects.filter(
    item__item_id__in=item_ids
).prefetch_related('user_set')
```

with only 2 db hits for the full query.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to retrieve all the users that own `all` of the specified item ids rather than all the users that own `either one` of the ids so `item__item__id__in` wouldn't work in my case.